# Key k returned by dict.keys() causes KeyError when doing dict[k]: KeyError on existing key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

The following code

```
for k in list(g_score.keys()):
    print(g_score[k])
```

returns a `KeyError` for me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./np.py", line 134, in <module>
    main()
  File "./np.py", line 131, in main
    NPuzzle(n).solve()
  File "./np.py", line 116, in solve
    print(g_score[k])
KeyError: 3
```

I don't understand how this is possible when `print(list(g_score.keys()))` is `[4, 3, 7]`. `3` is clearly in the dict.

---

For context, I'm trying to implement an A* search for the N-Puzzle problem (and I'm not even sure if the A* is implemented correctly since I can't get past this error), and have the following `State` class and `solve` function:

```
class State:
    def __init__(self, blank_idx, puzzle, g=0, h=0):
        self.blank_idx = blank_idx
        self.puzzle = puzzle
        self.f = g + h

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.puzzle == other.puzzle

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.f + self.blank_idx

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.f < other.f

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.f)
```

...

```
class NPuzzle:

    # ...other stuff

    def solve(self):
      start_state = State(
          self.puzzle.index(' '),
          self.puzzle,
          0,
          self.cost(self.puzzle)
      )

      g_score = {start_state: 0}
      open_set = [start_state]
      path = {}

      while open_set:
          state = open_set[0]

          if state.puzzle == self.goal_state:
              break

          heappop(open_set)
          for next_state in self.neighbors(state):
              g = g_score[state] + 1
              if next_state in g_score and g >= g_score[next_state]:
                  continue

              path[next_state] = state
              g_score[next_state] = g
              next_state.f = g + self.cost(next_state.puzzle)
              heappush(open_set, next_state)
```

and I first encountered the error on the line where I have:

```
g = g_score[state] + 1
```

I'm not sure really why this `KeyError` is occurring, but I'm assuming maybe it has to do with my custom `__hash()__` function.

Comment: I replace the definition of `__hash__` with `__hash__ = object.__hash__`. And there is no error but also never terminate. So the problem seems is really caused by hash function. Although I have no idea about how to implement this hash function with your purpose, you can just use default hash function to make it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so turns out the issue was that I was immediately changing the properties of the `State` instance that the hash function depended on...oops:

My `__hash()__` function for `State` is:

```
return self.f + self.blank_idx
```

and the way I was storing `State` in `g_score` is below:

```
g_score[next_state] = g
next_state.f = g + self.cost(next_state.puzzle)
```

Turns out the above breaks everything since it uses `next_state.f` to put `next_state` into `g_score`, but then immediately on the next line I mutate `next_state.f`

Switching the order of the two statements like so:

```
next_state.f = g + self.cost(next_state.puzzle)
g_score[next_state] = g
```

fixes my issue.